# Auto clip and append dots in WPF label

Tags: wpf, label, clipping

How can I auto clip text and append dots on a label if the current text doesn't fits to its width in WPF?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Put a TextBlock inside your label and set [TextTrimming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming) to CharacterEllipsis or WordEllipsis

```
<Label>
     <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis">Hello World</TextBlock>
</Label>
```

Comment: Hell no! This is what you hope for, but you know they couldn't have made it that easy! Really cool feature!

Comment: For some vague reason (is anything not vague in wpf?) this is working in my designer, but not at runtime

Comment: Nevermind, I needed to assign text to the textblock and not use label.Content anymore in my code.

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to use AccessText within the Label like this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
<Label VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="50"
        Target="{Binding ElementName=txtName}">
    <AccessText Text="_First Name" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"  />
</Label>
<TextBox Name="txtName" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120"/>
```

With this solution the access key for a control (e.g. Alt+F) still works.