# C# How can I make the text in a ListView column right-align instead of left-align?

Tags: c#, listview, text, alignment

I have a ListView in details view so it has 2 columns - but with the text which populates the list, it is more important to see the end of the text instead of the beginning.  Is there any way to set the listview to show the right-side of the text by default (ie have the ... at the beginning instead of the end if the text is too large to fit within the column)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ellipsis at start of string in WPF ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612774/ellipsis-at-start-of-string-in-wpf-listview)

Comment: you really should tell us what platform... silverlight? wpf? winforms? etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `RightToLeft` property on most controls which setting to true will change the alignment.