# how to add CharacterEllipsis at the beginning of the textblock in wpf?

Tags: wpf, text, character, ellipsis, trim

I have a `TextBlock` with `TextTrimming = TextTrimming.CharacterEllipsis` and I want the dots to appear at the beginging. Is there a property for this?

For example if I have the text "123456789ABCDEF" it is displayed "12345678...", but I want it "...89ABCDEF".

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a go at messing about with FlowDirection, it renders the ... at the beginning but still started with 1234 etc.

I did however come across this very similar question:

[Ellipsis at start of string in WPF ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612774/ellipsis-at-start-of-string-in-wpf-listview)

Someone there has a routine to do it manually. Hope that helps :)

Comment: I've made a more usable approach on that question, just check it out