# Change TextBlock Text in listBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, text, textblock, listboxitem

I have a `ListBox` which consists from items like this:

```
<ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=department}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBoxItem.ContentTemplate>
</ListBoxItem>
```

department is a string property :text="dept1\dept2\dept3\dept4\dept5\dept6"
My problem is that when `ListBox` size is changing I want to change the `TextBlock` text in this way: text= dept1\dept2\...\dept6.

the length of (dept1\dept2\...\dept6) is equal or less than `ListBoxItem` actual size.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the TextTrimming property of your TextBlock to CharacterEllipsis like this -

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=department}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
```

But this will show ellipsis at the end of the text if it gets greater than the size of the listboxitem. Something like this - "dept1\dept2\dept3\dept4\dept5..."

But however in case you want it in center, you might have to use `ValueConverter` to format the string. This might help - [Ellipsis at start of string in WPF ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612774/ellipsis-at-start-of-string-in-wpf-listview)