# WPF - Stretchable TextBlock on the left with max width and overlflow to the left

Tags: wpf, xaml, alignment, text-alignment

I want to add a `TextBlock`(or similar) to my window in WPF, but it must have the following properties:

- TextBlock starts at the left side of the window (in pseudocode: `TextBlock.Left == 0` regarding the parent's space)
- Grow to the right according to the text content (as the text increases, the `Width` increases, but the `Left`doesn't change)
- Do not grow beyond the parent's width (Pseudo: `TextBlock.MaxWidth == Parent.Width`)
- When text is longer than max width, the hidden part should be at the left! (No line breaks!!! Suppose I have the text "Hi, this is a text", the visible part should be "...is a text").

I can't seem to set a max width equal to the parent's size... shouldn't this be an easy thing to do?

I tried lots of combinations with grid, stack panel, text alignment, FlowDirection, HorizontalAlignment, none of what I tried could solve this which should be quite simple. Either my text ends up starting from the right side, or it starts from the left but overflows to the right.

How can I achieve this? Available solutions on stackoverflow all seem to have a fixed max width, which is not ok for my solution, I must make it follow the window.

Comment: @NEBEZ, updated the question with details, I hope it's clear now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ellipsis at start of string in WPF ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612774/ellipsis-at-start-of-string-in-wpf-listview)

Answer (score 0):

Make a class called TextBlockTrimmer and write the following.

```
enum EllipsisPosition
    {
        Start,
        Middle,
        End
    }

    [DefaultProperty("Content")]
    [ContentProperty("Content")]
    internal class TextBlockTrimmer : ContentControl
    {
        private class TextChangedEventScreener : IDisposable
        {
            private readonly TextBlockTrimmer _textBlockTrimmer;

            public TextChangedEventScreener(TextBlockTrimmer textBlockTrimmer)
            {
                _textBlockTrimmer = textBlockTrimmer;
                s_textPropertyDescriptor.RemoveValueChanged(textBlockTrimmer.Content,
                                                            textBlockTrimmer.TextBlock_TextChanged);
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                s_textPropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged(_textBlockTrimmer.Content,
                                                         _textBlockTrimmer.TextBlock_TextChanged);
            }
        }

        private static readonly DependencyPropertyDescriptor s_textPropertyDescriptor =
            DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(TextBlock.TextProperty, typeof(TextBlock));

        private const string ELLIPSIS = "...";

        private static readonly Size s_inifinitySize = new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity);

        public EllipsisPosition EllipsisPosition
        {
            get { return (EllipsisPosition)GetValue(EllipsisPositionProperty); }
            set { SetValue(EllipsisPositionProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty EllipsisPositionProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("EllipsisPosition",
                                        typeof(EllipsisPosition),
                                        typeof(TextBlockTrimmer),
                                        new PropertyMetadata(EllipsisPosition.End,
                                                             TextBlockTrimmer.OnEllipsisPositionChanged));

        private static void OnEllipsisPositionChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((TextBlockTrimmer)d).OnEllipsisPositionChanged((EllipsisPosition)e.OldValue,
                                                             (EllipsisPosition)e.NewValue);
        }

        private string _originalText;

        private Size _constraint;

        protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent)
        {
            var oldTextBlock = oldContent as TextBlock;
            if (oldTextBlock != null)
            {
                s_textPropertyDescriptor.RemoveValueChanged(oldTextBlock, TextBlock_TextChanged);
            }

            if (newContent != null && !(newContent is TextBlock))
                // ReSharper disable once LocalizableElement
                throw new ArgumentException("TextBlockTrimmer access only TextBlock content", nameof(newContent));

            var newTextBlock = (TextBlock)newContent;
            if (newTextBlock != null)
            {
                s_textPropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged(newTextBlock, TextBlock_TextChanged);
                _originalText = newTextBlock.Text;
            }
            else
                _originalText = null;

            base.OnContentChanged(oldContent, newContent);
        }


        private void TextBlock_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _originalText = ((TextBlock)sender).Text;
            this.TrimText();
        }

        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
        {
            _constraint = constraint;
            return base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
        }

        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
        {
            var result = base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeBounds);
            this.TrimText();
            return result;
        }

        private void OnEllipsisPositionChanged(EllipsisPosition oldValue, EllipsisPosition newValue)
        {
            this.TrimText();
        }

        private IDisposable BlockTextChangedEvent()
        {
            return new TextChangedEventScreener(this);
        }


        private static double MeasureString(TextBlock textBlock, string text)
        {
            textBlock.Text = text;
            textBlock.Measure(s_inifinitySize);
            return textBlock.DesiredSize.Width;
        }

        private void TrimText()
        {
            var textBlock = (TextBlock)this.Content;
            if (textBlock == null)
                return;

            if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(textBlock))
                return;


            var freeSize = _constraint.Width
                           - this.Padding.Left
                           - this.Padding.Right
                           - textBlock.Margin.Left
                           - textBlock.Margin.Right;

            // ReSharper disable once CompareOfFloatsByEqualityOperator
            if (freeSize <= 0)
                return;

            using (this.BlockTextChangedEvent())
            {
                // this actually sets textBlock's text back to its original value
                var desiredSize = TextBlockTrimmer.MeasureString(textBlock, _originalText);


                if (desiredSize <= freeSize)
                    return;

                var ellipsisSize = TextBlockTrimmer.MeasureString(textBlock, ELLIPSIS);
                freeSize -= ellipsisSize;
                var epsilon = ellipsisSize / 3;

                if (freeSize < epsilon)
                {
                    textBlock.Text = _originalText;
                    return;
                }

                var segments = new List<string>();

                var builder = new StringBuilder();

                switch (this.EllipsisPosition)
                {
                    case EllipsisPosition.End:
                        TextBlockTrimmer.TrimText(textBlock, _originalText, freeSize, segments, epsilon, false);
                        foreach (var segment in segments)
                            builder.Append(segment);
                        builder.Append(ELLIPSIS);
                        break;

                    case EllipsisPosition.Start:
                        TextBlockTrimmer.TrimText(textBlock, _originalText, freeSize, segments, epsilon, true);
                        builder.Append(ELLIPSIS);
                        foreach (var segment in ((IEnumerable<string>)segments).Reverse())
                            builder.Append(segment);
                        break;

                    case EllipsisPosition.Middle:
                        var textLength = _originalText.Length / 2;
                        var firstHalf = _originalText.Substring(0, textLength);
                        var secondHalf = _originalText.Substring(textLength);

                        freeSize /= 2;

                        TextBlockTrimmer.TrimText(textBlock, firstHalf, freeSize, segments, epsilon, false);
                        foreach (var segment in segments)
                            builder.Append(segment);
                        builder.Append(ELLIPSIS);

                        segments.Clear();

                        TextBlockTrimmer.TrimText(textBlock, secondHalf, freeSize, segments, epsilon, true);
                        foreach (var segment in ((IEnumerable<string>)segments).Reverse())
                            builder.Append(segment);
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new NotSupportedException();
                }

                textBlock.Text = builder.ToString();
            }
        }


        private static void TrimText(TextBlock textBlock,
                                     string text,
                                     double size,
                                     ICollection<string> segments,
                                     double epsilon,
                                     bool reversed)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (text.Length == 1)
                {
                    var textSize = TextBlockTrimmer.MeasureString(textBlock, text);
                    if (textSize <= size)
                        segments.Add(text);

                    return;
                }

                var halfLength = Math.Max(1, text.Length / 2);
                var firstHalf = reversed ? text.Substring(halfLength) : text.Substring(0, halfLength);
                var remainingSize = size - TextBlockTrimmer.MeasureString(textBlock, firstHalf);
                if (remainingSize < 0)
                {
                    // only one character and it's still too large for the room, skip it
                    if (firstHalf.Length == 1)
                        return;

                    text = firstHalf;
                    continue;
                }

                segments.Add(firstHalf);

                if (remainingSize > epsilon)
                {
                    var secondHalf = reversed ? text.Substring(0, halfLength) : text.Substring(halfLength);
                    text = secondHalf;
                    size = remainingSize;
                    continue;
                }

                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then use it as follows:

```
<local:TextBlockTrimmer EllipsisPosition="Start" Grid.Column="0">
            <TextBlock Text="Excuse me but can I be you for a while"
               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
</local:TextBlockTrimmer>
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612774/ellipsis-at-start-of-string-in-wpf-listview)